# How do I check for presence of a bit in C# using AND?

Tags: c#, active-directory, byte, boolean-logic

How to I use logical operators to determine if a bit is set, or is bit-shifting the only way?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431732/c-checking-if-a-bit-is-set-or-not) that uses bit shifting, but I would think I can just `AND` out my value.

For some context, I'm reading a value from Active Directory and trying to determine if it a Schema Base Object. I think my problem is a syntax issue, but I'm not sure how to correct it.

```
foreach (DirectoryEntry schemaObjectToTest in objSchema.Children)
        {
            var resFlag = schemaObjectToTest.Properties["systemFlags"].Value;
            //if bit 10 is set then can't be made confidential.
            if (resFlag != null)
            {
                byte original = Convert.ToByte( resFlag );
                byte isFlag_Schema_Base_Object = Convert.ToByte( 2);
                var result = original & isFlag_Schema_Base_Object;
                if ((result) > 0)
                {
                       //A non zero result indicates that the bit was found
                }
            }
        }
```

When I look at the debugger:
`resFlag` is an `object{int}` and the value is `0x00000010`. 
`isFlag_Schema_Base_Object`, is `0x02`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`resFlag` is `0x00000010` which is 16 in decimal, or `10000` in binary. So it seems like you want to test bit 4 (with bit 0 being the least significant bit), despite your comment saying "if bit 10 is set".

If you do need to test bit 4, then `isFlag_Schema_Base_Object` needs to be initialised to 16, which is `0x10`.

Anyway, you are right - you don't need to do bit shifting to see if a bit is set, you can `AND` the value with a constant that has just that bit set, and see if the result is non-zero.

If the bit is set:

```
                 original  xxx1xxxx
                      AND
isFlag_Schema_Base_Object  00010000
-----------------------------------
                        =  00010000 (non-zero)
```

But if the bit isn't set:

```
                 original  xxx0xxxx
                      AND
isFlag_Schema_Base_Object  00010000
-----------------------------------
                        =  00000000 (zero)
```

Having said that, it might be clearer to initialise `isFlag_Schema_Base_Object` using the value `1<<4`, to make it clear that you're testing whether bit 4 is set.

Comment: Just to clarify, will my AND be nonzero if resflag is: 0x00011010?  That is my goal.

Comment: Yes - as long as `isFlag_Schema_Base_Object` itself has only one bit set, then `AND`ing it with `original` will give you either zero (if the bit is set), or `isFlag_Schema_Base_Object` (non-zero, meaning the bit is set). You can test either whether the result is zero/non-zero, or whether it's equal/not equal to `isFlag_Schema_Base_Object`. The tests are equivalent. And if you're in any doubt, try it out :-)

Comment: @MakerOfThings7: Yup. Your AND will result in 0 for the other bits, but 1 for the one you're checking (if and only if that bit you're checking is set).

Answer (score 0):

If you know which bit to check and you're dealing with int's you can use [BitVector32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx?queryresult=true).

```
int yourValue = 5;
BitVector32 bv = new BitVector32(yourValue);
int bitPositionToCheck = 3;
int mask = Enumerable.Range(0, bitPositionToCheck).Select(BitVector32.CreateMask).Last();
bool isSet = bv[mask];
```

Using bitshifting is probably cleaner than using CreateMask. But it's there :)