# How to check if a particular bit is set in C#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bit

In C#, I have a 32 bit value which I am storing in an int. I need to see if a particular bit is set. The bit I need is `0x00010000`.

I came up with this solution:

Here is what I am looking for:

```
Hex:       0    0    0    1     0    0    0    0    0 
Binary   0000|0000|0000|0001|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000
```

So I right bit shift 16, which would give me:

```
Hex:       0    0    0    0     0    0    0    0    1
Binary   0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0001
```

I then bit shift left 3, which would give me:

```
Hex:       0    0    0    0     0    0    0    0   8 
Binary   0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|0000|1000
```

I then case my 32 bit value to a byte, and see if it equals 8.

So my code would be something like this:

```
int value = 0x102F1032;
value = value >> 16;
byte bits = (byte)value << 3;
bits == 8 ? true : false;
```

Is there a simpler way to check if a particular bit is set without all the shifting?

Comment: You just need to use the bitwise & operator for this.

Comment: cant you just write (number & 0x00010000 ) != 0 ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, even though shifting isn't the best way of doing this, why didn't you just check if the result was 1 after the first shift? i.e. why shift back left 3?

Comment: @Ray Yes odd logic to shift right by a certain amount of places then immediately shift left by another amount...

Comment: @Ray I did it that way because any of the other bits could be set, I did the shift to bring in 0's so that I could be sure that no other bits were set. If other bits were set, I wouldnt know what to compare it to. If I do it that way, I am sure that it will be 8.

Comment: @user489041 but the bit to the left of your tested bit could still be set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# :: Checking if a bit is set or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431732/c-sharp-checking-if-a-bit-is-set-or-not)

Comment: @Ray I thought if I casted it to a byte, then the bits to the left would be dropped off? But, this is why I am glad I asked this question. I wasnt sure on a a lot of this.

Comment: @user489041 a byte would still be too big, since it's 8 bits not 4. But yeah I see what you're trying to do now.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the bitwise & operator:

```
int value = 0x102F1032;
int checkBit = 0x00010000;
bool hasBit = (value & checkBit) == checkBit;
```

Answer (score 14):

It's much easier than that. Just use the bitwise `AND` operator like this

```
(value & 0x00010000) != 0
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just check like so:

```
bool bitSet = (value & 0x10000) == 0x10000;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just do a bitwise AND.

```
int result = yourByte & 16;
if (result != 0)
{
    // do what you need to when that bit is set
}
```

Comment: Just be careful with this one. 0x10000 != 16.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [bitwise and operator `&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx):

```
return (value & 0x100000) != 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

And if you don't like the bit mask approach:

```
int data = 0;

var bits = new BitArray(new int[] { data });

bits.Get(21);
```

(I may have got the wrong count and it's not 21 you are looking for)

This might me a bit abusive for a case where you only have 32 bits, but if you need to work with longer bit arrays this is much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

you can say:

```
if( (number & 0x00010000 ) != 0 )
{
  //the bit is set...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int someInt = 8;
int BitToTest = 3;
bool isSet = (someInt & (1 << BitToTest)) != 0;
```

And it with the shifted value, bit is set if the answer is nonzero.
If you are doing one bit a lot use a constant for (1 << BitToTest), if a lot but different bits, a static array to look up 2 ^ BitToTest.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, but maybe not better you can use the [BitVector32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx) structure.

```
int value =  0x102F1032;
var vector = new BitVector32(value);
return vector[0x1000]; //true
```