# How to know what check box are checked based on the sum?

Tags: c#

I have a seven check box each check box have corresponding values.

Here are the values:

> No Business Activity - 1
>   Low/Nil Inventory - 2 
>   Poor Location - 4 
>   Bad Credit Reputation - 8
>   Slow Moving Goods - 16
>   With Known Collection Problems - 32
>   Poor Management - 64

Each check values will be sum for example like in the image below the first 3 items are checked so the total is 7. This total is being saved in the database. My problem is this, when I update the total the how can I know what checkbox should be checked?

For example (I cannot express clearly what I am trying to achieve):

7 is the total so when I display the negative factors again the first 3 items should be check.

Another,
The total is 36 when I display the negative factors the 3rd and 6th checkbox is the only checked items

Watch this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsxT4FfRBaM) video here is what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Interface Image]

Comment: *"how can I know what checkbox should be checked"* - [check which bit is set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2431732/1997232), e.g. bit 0 is "no bisness activity" checkbox, if it is set - set checkbox.

Comment: @Sinatr can you show me the specifics?

Comment: If you want to keep this approch and the list items are limited you should use powers of 10 for setting the value, 1,10,100 ..., will be more easy to see which checkbox was checked

Comment: @LucianBumb the requirement is I use this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to convert the total into a binary and based on the binary if 1 = checked if 0 = uncheck.

Use this code:

```
int decVal;
int val;
string a = "";

decVal = 34;
Console.WriteLine("Decimal: {0}", decVal);

while (decVal >= 1) {
  val = decVal / 2;
  a += (decVal % 2).ToString();
  decVal = val;
}
string binValue = "";

for (int i = a.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  binValue = binValue + a[i];
}

Console.WriteLine("Binary: {0}", binValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all your checkboxes in an array, in order of 1 to 64:

```
CheckBox[] cb = new Checkbox[]{
  NoBusinessActivityCb,
  LowNilInventoryCb,
  PoorLocationCb,
  BadCreditReputationCb,
  SlowMovingGoodsCb,
  WithKnownCollectionProblemsCb,
  PoorManagementCb
}
```

Now hopefully you can agree that 2 to the power of the index in the array, is the value the checkbox represents:

```
2^0 = 1, which is the value for NoBusinessActivity, at index 0
2^6 = 64, which is the value for PoorManagement, at index 6
```

etc

Now if you iterate backwards over the array, asking if the number you have is bigger than the 2^index, and if it is, check the box and subtract the pow from the number:

```
int number = 36;

for(int i = cb.Length - 1; i >= 0 && number > 0; i--){
  if(Math.Pow(2,i) <= number){
    cb[i].Checked = true;
    number -= Math.Pow(2, i);
  }
}
```

This implements the logic of :

```
is 36 >= 64 ? no
is 36 >= 32 ? yes, check "WitkNownProblems" and do 36 - 32 -> new number 4
is 16 >= 4 ? no
is 8 >= 4 ? no
is 4 >= 4 ? yes, check "PoorLocation" ...
```

You should set all the checkboxes to unchecked before you do this loop

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to iterate through a range of tests ..
Example 1. if you get value 10

1. First check if you have a checkbox with value 10 if false continue
2. Get sum of all checkbox'es under 10. (8+4+2+1) If != 10 continue
3. Substract biggest value from 10 and check if it exist (10-8 =2). 2
   exists so the result is 8 and 2

Example 2. if you get value 30

1. First check if you have a checkbox with value 30 if false continue
2. Get sum of all checkbox'es under 30. (16+8+4+2+1) If != 30 continue
3. Substract biggest value from 30 and check if it exist (30-16 = 14). 14 does not exist so now you try again substract biggest number below 14 from 14 (14-8 = 6). 6 does not exist so now you try again substract biggest number below 6 from 6 (6-4 = 2). 2 exists so your result is 16+8+4+2.

Example 3. if you get value 7

1. First check if you have a checkbox with value 7 if false continue
2. Get sum of all checkbox'es under 7. (4+2+1) If != 7 continue

So you just have to write three test methods that performs these tests. The two first are plain tests and last is a recursive test

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get selected items, can be like this:

```
private static List<int> GetSelectedItems(int sum)
        {
            var rest = new List<int>();
            var items = new List<int> { 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 };
            foreach (var item in items.OrderByDescending(a=>a))
            {
                if(sum>=item)
                {
                    rest.Add(item);
                    sum = sum - item;
                }
            }
            return rest;
        }
```