# Solidity: Checking if specific bit is set in bytes24

Tags: ethereum, solidity, bit-shift, bitwise-and

I'm trying to implement a function in Solidity that checks if the bit at a position is set or not, i.e. I want a function like:

```
function isBitSet(bytes24 b, uint pos) returns (bool){
    return ...
}
```

I tried to transfer this approach to Solidity: [Checking if a bit is set or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431732/checking-if-a-bit-is-set-or-not)

```
function isBitSet(bytes24 b, uint pos) returns (bool){
    return (b & (1 << pos)) != 0;
}
```

However, this does not work because `(1 << pos)` returns type `uint256`...

Comment: Maybe consider right shift `(b >> pos) & 1) == 1` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function isBitSet(bytes24 b, uint pos) internal view returns (bool){
    return (  bytes32(b) & bytes32(1 << (pos+64)) ) != 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27780780)